# Sort file 'per paragraph' in Vim

Tags: vim

Given a file that looks like:

```
Crab
  some text that doesn't need sorting.
  more textual descriptination
Albatross
  some text or other
  perhaps a list that needs no sorting:
    1. a
    2. bee
Dolphin
Pterodactyl
  long story about this particular animal.
```

How would I tell Vim (version 7) to sort this file alphabetically by animal name? Impossible? How else would one sort this file?

Comment: This vim addon https://github.com/vim-scripts/AdvancedSorters seems to do this, but I've not tested it, as the `expr` seems a bit difficult to fiddle out..

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, you can do it in vim:

```
:%s/$/$/
:g/^\w/s/^/\r/
:1del t | $put t
:g/^\w/,/^$/-1join!
:sort
:%s/\$/\r/g
:g/^$/d
```

output

```
Albatross
  some text or other
  perhaps a list that needs no sorting:
    1. a
    2. bee
Crab
  some text that doesn't need sorting.
  more textual descriptination
Dolphin
Pterodactyl
  long story about this particular animal.
```

---

You should use a special char to indicate EOL(other than `$`)!

Answer (score 3):

> **How else would one sort this file?**

```
$perl sortparagraphs animals.txt

Albatross
  some text or other
  perhaps a list that needs no sorting:
    1. a
    2. bee
Crab
  some text that doesn't need sorting.
  more textual descriptination
Dolphin
Pterodactyl
  long story about this particular animal.
```

Where sortparagraphs is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($paragraph, @list);
while(<>) {
  if (/^\S/) {
    push @list, $paragraph if $paragraph;
    $paragraph = '';
  }
  $paragraph .= $_;
}
push @list, $paragraph if $paragraph;
print sort @list;
```

There is probably a better Perl solution but the above is a quick answer.

If the file is larger than memory, it might be sensible to transform the file into a line per animal, sort and finally transform back.